# how to run a cucumber junit project from command line using verify

Tags: java, junit, command-line, automation, cucumber

I have an automation framework using `cucumber` and run as `Junit` test case. How can I run from command line using `verify`?

Right now I am right clicking on test runner class and run as junit test case.

I tried `mvn test verify` but it doesn't run the specific test runner class.

Comment: Just run `mvn verify`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `mvn verify` Failsafe is used and test should be named accordingly:

> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html
> Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests Inclusions
>
> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test
> classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
> "**/IT*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "IT".
> "**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "IT".
> "**/*ITCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "ITCase".
> ```
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions,
> then configure Failsafe Plugin and specify the tests you want to
> include.

When using `mvn test` Surefire is used and test should be named accordingly:

> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html
> Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests Inclusions
>
> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
> classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
> "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
> ```
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions,
> then configure Surefire Plugin and specify the tests you want to
> include.